# How to compile TypeScript and run the result .js file in one build in sublime Text 3?

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3

I've already successfully installed TypeScript plugin on Sublime Text 3. After the plugin is installed, it has a build system added to the menu.

[image]

You can just use "Command + B" to build .ts file.

What I want is to compile .ts to .js and run the result js file using "node xxx.js" in one "Command + B" command.

How do I configure sublime text 3 build system to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both `tsc` and `node` are in your system `PATH`, the following configuration should work:

```
{
  "cmd": ["tsc $file && node $file_base_name.js"],
  "shell": true,
  "selector": "*.ts"
}
```

See [Build Systems – Configuration](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html) for more on what is going on here.